# Upload file from out of haddop cluster(remote windows machine) to hdfs just like hue upload

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hue

I am trying to find out a solution for copying a file from my local windows machine or local linux machine to hdfs on cloud.

I know one solution,

> remote -> cluster node (using scp)
>
> node -> hdfs (using hdfs command)

But for my use case it does not works, I need to find out a solution which directly upload files from local to hdfs like hue does for upload.

I also tried following command

> hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal file:://<'local-host'>:<'local-path'> hdfs://<'hdfs-path'>

But it through following error:

> copyFromLocal: `<'local-path'>': No such file or directory

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

-Thanks

Vikash

Answer (score 0):

See to that you create the dir first in hdfs and then,

```
hadoop fs -put /path/in/linux /hdfs/path
```

or

```
hadoop fs -copyFromLocal /path/in/linux /hdfs/path
```

Comment: Thanks for response.

This is correct for local linux to hdfs but my question is for copying from remote windows machine to hdfs.

Comment: `cat <file_name> | ssh username@masternode "hadoop dfs -put - hadoopFoldername/"` Check this: [Hadoop - copy directly to hdfs from external machine](http://one-line-it.blogspot.de/2013/05/hadoop-copy-directly-to-hdfs-from.html)

Comment: I figured out hue implementation, and it is not possible to copy file/s from remote location to hdfs directly.
We need to copy files to staging location then we can move to hdfs.
Now I have only one path for this

    remote -> cluster node (using scp)

    node -> hdfs (using hdfs command)